# xcode - organize the code (straighten)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is there a way to organize the the position of the code (straighten ...) automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit menu > Format > Re-indent.

Comment: In Xcode prefs, you can go to the Key Bindings section and give this command a keyboard shortcut.  I've given it Shift-Cmd-I, for convenience.  Then you don't have to use your mouse to re-indent.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>). Then scroll along the top to the right and click the "Indent" header. There should be an option called something like "Indent text automatically." That should do what you want. :)

Comment: NP, make sure you check this option, so you don't have to worry about indentation on any new code you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the code and then choose "Reindent selection" from the context menu.